Pagination with dynamic page number navigation
so, I want to create view shown in a image.
it's a UI of project I am working on !!
first I thought I should use recycler view and all but then I thought logic will be super difficult !!
now I am lost
I literally have no idea !!

so as i told you i thought of recycler view with custom logic!!
and it worked !!
as per requirement i want new list with the size of 5
so, i have made my own logic
fun main() {
    var l: ArrayList<Int?> = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    newList(l, 5)
    }
   
fun newList(list: ArrayList<Int?>, selected: Int = 1): ArrayList<Int?> 
   {

    var newList: ArrayList<Int?> = arrayListOf()

    if (list.size <= 5) {
        return list
    }
    if (selected == 1 || selected == list.size || list.size - selected == 1) {
        newList = arrayListOf(1, 2, null, list.size - 1, list.size)

    } else if (selected - 1 >= 2) {
        newList = arrayListOf(1, null, selected)
        if (list.size - selected >= 2) {
            newList.add(null)
            newList.add(list.size)
        }

    } else if (selected - 1 == 1) {
        newList = arrayListOf(1, selected, null, list.size - 1, list.size)
    }

    return newList
}

